# SQL - Retrieve closest value DOWN

Tags: sql, mariadb

here is my current sql:

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE trumped = 1
ORDER BY ABS( `value` - 12110433 )
limit 3
```

This correctly returns the row with the closest value: **12313672**. However, I need to be able to pull the closest lower number value. (The closest number below 12110433)

I've tried using methods with `top 1` however this errors for me so I cannot use it.

I also need to run this very often and quickly, will it be taxing on my database?

Thank you

Comment: can you tag the dbms being used?

Comment: MariaDB is what I have installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it with `union all`.

```
(SELECT * FROM items
WHERE trumped = 1 AND `value`>=12110433
ORDER BY `value`-12110433
limit 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM items
WHERE trumped = 1 AND `value`<12110433
ORDER BY 12110433-`value`
limit 1)
```

If you are using MariaDB versions 10.2 and later, this can be achieved with `row_number` function.

```
select *
from (select i.*,
      row_number() over(order by case when 12110433-`value`<0 then 1 else 0 end,`value`) as rnum_above,
      row_number() over(order by case when 12110433-`value`>0 then 1 else 0 end,`value`) as rnum_below
      from items i
     ) t
where 1 in (rnum_below,rnum_above)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems to return two results and the first one is still higher than the value. Here's a pic: https://i.gyazo.com/4f10c1ea4a4056f1f47626e12da6963e.png

Comment: Should I put a selected around all of that and order by value asc?

Comment: did you not need 2 values, one lesser and the other greater?

Comment: So easy, I feel silly. Didn't realise each query were doing separate jobs. I was over complicating myself haha thank you

Comment: check out the edit which shows one more way of achieving the same result..provided you are using version 10.2 and later..

Comment: Does the `row_number` version run faster or more efficiently? Or just another way to do it? :)

Comment: Why all the complexity, the OP only asks for one row?  `I need to be able to pull the closest lower number value. (The closest number below 12110433)`

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way would be:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM items i
WHERE i.trumped = 1 AND value < 12110433
ORDER BY value DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

For performance, you want an index on `items(trumped, value)`.